Having issues interpolating props into Image source in React Native
I'm having trouble interpolating a string into a source prop for the Image component in my React Native app. For reference all the images live locally in the app and I'm trying to generate a FlatList of this individual NovelItem component.
Here's what my code looks like:
import { Image, Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { GlobalStyles } from "../../constants/styles";

const NovelItem = ({
  id,
  title,
  authors,
  releaseDate,
  image,
  setSummaryModalOpen,
}) => {
  const imageString = `../../assets/images/covers/${image}`

  const renderAuthorNames = authors.map((author, index, arr) => {
    if (index !== arr.length - 1) {
      return <Text style={styles.authorName}>{author}, </Text>;
    }

    console.log(`COVER IMAGE:  ${imageString}`)

    return <Text style={styles.authorName}>{author}</Text>;
  });

  const summaryButtonHandler = () => {
    setSummaryModalOpen({ isOpen: true, novelId: id });
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Image
          source={require(imageString)}
          style={styles.image}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.infoSection}>
        <View style={styles.novelInfo}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{title.toUpperCase()}</Text>
          <View style={styles.authorNames}>{renderAuthorNames}</View>
          <Text style={styles.releaseDate}>Released On: {releaseDate}</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Pressable
            style={({ pressed }) => [pressed && styles.pressed]}
            onPress={summaryButtonHandler}
          >
            <Text style={styles.textButton}>View Summary</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

I've tried requiring each of the images in the local file like such:
require("../../assets/images/covers/SomeCover.jpeg")

I've tried using URI in the source like such:
         <Image
          source={{uri: imageString}}
          style={styles.image}
        />

These are non static images since they are pulled from the props but the actual images do live in the project locally.
This is the specific error I'm currently getting:
error: components/Novels/NovelItem.js: components/Novels/NovelItem.js:Invalid call at line 33: require(imageString)


I faced a similar kind of issue.
I had the below file for image constants:
const wImages = {
    802: "assets/day.png",
    803: "assets/night.png",
}

And want to use that as:
const [value, setValue] = useState(802)

<Image source={require(wImages[value])} style={styles.weatherImage} />

But not able to use that, I found that require function is a compile-time construct in JavaScript, meaning its argument must be a static string known at compile time. It cannot accept dynamic values like a variable value.
So finally I figured it out by adding require in my global variable itself.
const wImages = {
    802: require("assets/day.png"),
    803: require("assets/night.png"),
}

And able to use as below:
<Image source={wImages[value]} style={styles.weatherImage} />

So you have to create one global file which may be like this
const images = {
  image1: require("../../assets/images/covers/image1"),
  image2: require("../../assets/images/covers/image2"),
  image3: require("../../assets/images/covers/image3"),
  ... 
}

and use that as
   <Image
      source={images[image]}   //here image is variable which contains like image1, image2, ...
      style={styles.image}
    />


Hey thanks a ton for your response. This appears to have resolved my issue. I appreciate you not only answering how to fix it but why and with clear demonstrations as far as how it looked in your code as well as how it looks in generic code it made it easy to translate into my code base and now I know what the underlying issue was. Marked as correct answer.
